# Regex to match multiple numbers within string

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that looks like this to extract order numbers from columns:

```
df["Orders"].str.extract('([0-9]{9,10}[/+ #_;.-]?)')
```

The orders column can look like this:

```
12
123456789
1234567890
123456789/1234567890
123456789/1/123456789
123456789+1234567890
```

The resulting new column in the dataframe after the regex should look like this:

```
NaN
123456789
1234567890
123456789/1234567890
123456789/123456789
123456789+1234567890
```

However, with my current regex I'm getting the following result:

```
NaN
123456789
1234567890
123456789/
123456789/
123456789+
```

How can I get the result that I'm looking for?

Comment: Does `df["Orders"].str.findall(r'[/+ #_;.-]?\b[0-9]{9,10}\b').str.join('')` help?

Comment: @j1-lee the orders proceeding slashes, plus signs, hashtags, etc that match 9 or 10 digits are actually orders. They will then eventually be exploded to create many different rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Orders':['12','123456789','1234567890','123456789/1234567890','123456789/1/123456789','123456789+1234567890', 'Order number: 6508955960_000010_1005500']})
df["Result"] = df["Orders"].str.findall(r'[/+ #_;.-]?(?<![0-9])[0-9]{9,10}(?![0-9])').str.join('').str.lstrip('/+ #_;.-')
df.loc[df['Result'] == '', 'Result'] = np.nan
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yaWEgE/3). *Details*

- `[/+ #_;.-]?(?<![0-9])[0-9]{9,10}(?![0-9])` - matches an optional `/`, `+`, space, `#`, `_`, `;`, `.` or `-` char, and then none or ten digit number not enclosed with other digits
- `Series.str.findall` extracts all occurrences
- `.str.join('')` concatenates the matches into a single string
- `.str.lstrip('/+ #_;.-')` - removes the special chars that were matched with the number at the beginning of the string
- `df.loc[df['Result'] == '', 'Result'] = np.nan` - if needed - replaces empty strings with `np.nan` values in the `Result` column.

Output:

```py
>>> df
                  Orders                Result
0                    NaN                   NaN
1              123456789             123456789
2             1234567890            1234567890
3   123456789/1234567890  123456789/1234567890
4  123456789/1/123456789   123456789/123456789
5   123456789+1234567890  123456789+1234567890
>>>
```

Comment: Hmm, something like this: `Order number: 6508955960_000010_1005500` returns a blank...This should return `6508955960`

Comment: @user2896120 Switch to numeric boundaries.

Comment: Thank you this fixes it, is there a way to remove leading `#,+,etc.` so that it would remove something like #6508955960 within the regex? Or would it just be easier to do a ltrim

Comment: @user2896120 With regex, it will add complexity to pattern matching. I'd just use `lstrip`

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the next code to work with data frames,

RegExp: `(?:^|([/+ #_;.-]))(?:\d{1,8})(?!\d)`

- `(?:\d{1,8})(?!\d)` - find a number (<9 digits)
- `([/+ #_;.-])` - preceded by one/none of the possible delimiters (group #1)

Conditionally replace with `NaN` or empty string - `subst` uses `match.group(1)` to differ between the two options:

- standalone-invalid - `12`
- invalid-with-delimiter - `/1`

```py
import re

regex = r"(?:^|([/+ #_;.-]))(?:\d{1,8})(?!\d)"

test_str = ("12\n"
            "123456789\n"
            "1234567890\n"
            "123456789/1234567890\n"
            "123456789/1/123456789\n"
            "123456789+1234567890")

def subst(match):
    m = match.group(1)
    return "" if m else "NaN"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
NaN
123456789
1234567890
123456789/1234567890
123456789/123456789
123456789+1234567890
```